# Databinding and bound buttons

Tags: wpf, binding

I have an ItemsControl bound to a list of objects.

It basically displays a list of bound properties on screen with a textbox and button next to each one to allow you to add additional information to each database field.

In the onclick of the button I need to take the string in the textbox and store it in the object for that item. The XAML looks a bit like this

```
            <ItemsControl x:Name="ListDatabaseFields"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedImport.ColumnMappings}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DatabaseColumn.Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <TextBox Name="txtNewFileField" Width="100"/>
                                <Button Name="Add" Content="Add File Field" Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" Width="50" Click="Add_Click"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Whats the best way in the XAML to access the ColumnMapping the itemcontrol is bound to for that item and change its file field property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understood your question correctly, please clarify if this is not what you are looking for.

---

I have adapted this to my test application, my DataTemplate looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBox MinWidth="100" Name="tbNewName"/>
        <Button MinWidth="100"
                Tag="{x:Reference tbNewName}" Click="ButtonNewName_Click"
                Content="Do Stuff"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Notice the `Button.Tag` which references the `TextBox`, i can use it in the handler like this:

```
private void ButtonNewName_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Employee emp = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Employee;
    TextBox tbNewName = (sender as FrameworkElement).Tag as TextBox;
    emp.Name = tbNewName.Text;
}
```

The `DataContext` is inherited, so the sender (the Button) contains the data-item, in your case a `ColumnMapping`, the `Tag` gives me the `TextBox` and that is all i need for changing a property.

If you need to reference more controls you could create an array in the `Tag`.